# Error reading JSON from URL

Tags: c#, json, url

I am trying to read json into my C# application from a url. When I run the application I keep getting a error:

"Additional Text encountered after finished reading JSON content: {. Path ",line 2, position 667".

This is from this [URL](http://cbbnideas.com/brydens-website/products/?category=Alcopops)

I checked the page and the view source and can't seem to find the problem. How do I fix this?

The JSON is derived from a php array that is json encoded and echoed:

```
    $args = array( 'post_type' => 'product', 'posts_per_page' => 200, 'product_cat' => 'Alcopops' );

    $loop = new WP_Query( $args );

    while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); 
    global $product; 
echo json_encode($product);

    endwhile; 


    wp_reset_query();
```

Comment: Surround Json with square brackets.

Comment: did you use `WebClient`?

Comment: @SirwanAfifi I used `HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
               // HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(App.DataServiceUrl + "/products?category=" + (String)navigationParameter);`

Comment: @BappiDatta. I did that and now I get another error message: "After parsing a value an unexpected character was encountered: {. Path '[0]',line 2, position 668."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That page doesn't contain valid json. Take a look at this:

> "product_type":"simple"}{"id":246,"post":

there's no comma between } and {

Edit:

The problem is with your php, rather than the c#.

Try this:

```
$args = array( 'post_type' => 'product', 'posts_per_page' => 200, 'product_cat' => 'Alcopops' );
$loop = new WP_Query( $args );
echo json_encode($loop->get_posts());
wp_reset_query();
```

Comment: Ok, well I am using json_encode to get a php array in this format.

Comment: Really! Can you show the code where you're building the array and calling json_encode? Something funny there.

Comment: Are you looping over each element in the array and calling json_encode for each element by any chance?

Answer (score 0):

use `WebClient` :

```
var json = new WebClient().DownloadString("http://cbbnideas.com/brydens-website/products/?category=Alcopops");
```

Comment: This is for a windows 8 desktop app. I doesn't seem to recognize WebClient

Comment: @add `using System.Net;`

Comment: [Client profile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc656912%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) does not have System.Web.dll so you can't really use WebClient in an app that targets client profile.